# 特定ユーザーのみが利用できるアプリが、App Store のガイドライン 3.2 を理由にリジェクトされてしまう

Tags: app-store

特定の企業とその代理店の従業員のみが利用可能なアプリを制作し、公開することを試みています。
起動時に規約同意画面、次にログイン画面が表示され、ログインに成功すると本機能を利用できるという仕様です。
ログインのためのid,パスワードは弊社が利用企業に事前にお知らせする形式で、アプリ内でアカウントを発行する機能はありません。

Apple Store Connect に公開申請をしましたが、下記の理由でリジェクトされてしまいました。

> Regarding the guideline 3.2, we continue to find that your app was
> designed for a specific business or organization, including its
> partners, clients or employees, and not for general distribution on
> the App Store. Business apps available on the App Store are meant for
> use by a wide variety of external customers around the world. As this
> app is not intended for general distribution, it cannot be made
> available on the App Store. We encourage you to review the other ways
> to distribute your business app and choose one that better meets your
> business needs.

特定のユーザーへの限定公開ではなく、あらゆる人が利用するアプリでなければApp Storeでは公開することはできないという内容ですが、実際には下記に示したいくつかのアプリのように、特定のユーザー、顧客、企業のみが利用できるアプリが公開されています。

- [JISP](https://apps.apple.com/jp/app/id1457808505)

  > このアプリは、事前の申請と承認によりアカウントが発行されたユーザにご利用いただける専用アプリケーションです。アカウントをお持ちでない方はご利用になれません。
- [保険料計算](https://apps.apple.com/jp/app/id1368323142)

  > 本アプリはエヌエヌ生命保険株式会社の社員専用です。社員以外はご利用いただけません。
- [保険製作所アプリ](https://apps.apple.com/jp/app/id1488715851)

  > 保険製作所のお客さま専用アプリです。

In-house での配布や、apple bussines manger での配布も検討しましたが、本件は複数法人での配布であること、配布対象になる人数が多数になることから、Apple Storeでの公開を考えています。

上記のアプリは審査に通っているようなので、本件の状況でも公開可能なはずです。
同様の状況で公開を許可された方、または対応策をご存知の方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

似たようなアプリを数々リリースしてきました。
これという対応策はないのですが、とりあえずAppleと連絡を取り続けてください。